# Hadoop can't start. Getting error "sed: can't read : No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, hadoop

I have freshly installed hadoop.
However, running `start-all.sh` does not start hadoop. The following is the output.\

```
$ start-all.sh                                                               
                 
WARNING: Attempting to start all Apache Hadoop daemons as mark in 10 seconds.
WARNING: This is not a recommended production deployment configuration.
WARNING: Use CTRL-C to abort.
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
Starting datanodes
sed: can't read : No such file or directory
Starting secondary namenodes [makali]
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Starting resourcemanager
Starting nodemanagers
sed: can't read : No such file or directory
```

`whereis hadoop` works fine

```
hadoop: /usr/local/hadoop /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop
```

Comment: edit your question to show the contents of `start-all.sh` or at least any `sed` commands after `Starting nodemanagers` is printed (may be in a "sub" script that gets called from the "parent". Good luck.

Comment: `whereis` doesn't execute anything, so I'm not sure what that proves... `start-all` script isn't really recommended to use. Try `hdfs namenode start` and `hdfs datanode start` in separate terminals, and see if there are errors